# Running Ubuntu Headless

Tags: headless

I would like to run Ubuntu headless , keyboard less, and mouse less.  I plan on logging in remotely to the box from a Mac. The primary reason for doing this is lack of space.  How can I install and setup this up without hassles?  Meaning, I don't want to have recompile my kernel or tweak driver settings.

Thanks

Comment: Log in graphically? Or just a command line like SSH?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using only the command line, then SSH is the way to go. There is an excellent tutorial in the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/serverguide/openssh-server.html).
If you are interested in desktop sharing, then you need VNC or something similar. Take a look at [this help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-desktop.html).

Comment: I plan on using the X11 server software on my Mac to access manipulate the desktop.